# How to implement border-radius to HTML

Tags: html, css

At first, I am new with coding. I am trying to implement border radius to my portfolio website (created by bootstrap template) based on this:
https://codepen.io/enbee81/pen/LBMKqV

I am a little bit stuck because I have sections in my code and my photo is under one of these. See code:

```
<section class="py-5 text-center container">
    <div class="row py-lg-5">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="fw-light">Random Text</h1>
        <p class="lead text-muted">Random Text</p>
        <p>
          <a href="mailto:email" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Email Me</a>
          <a href="github" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Check my GitHub</a>
        </p>
          <h2 class="image_class">
           
        <img src="{% static 'image.png' %}" height = 400 > </img> 
        
          </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

When I put HTML code and CSS code in `<style></style>` before above code the whole website is broken and the image is generated above my original and even the whole section. In which part of my code should I implement border radius to be working only in this section and with my photo which is given by `<img src="{% static 'image.png' %}"` ?

Thanks for explanation and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Why do you put the image inside the heading?

Comment: Yeah, I did this because I thought I can refer by this to class =image_class but even without it is not working.

Comment: What happens if you move the image outside of the h2? Or try <img class="image_class"> without the H2.  Can you make a codepen.io of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="border-radius: 50%;">
```

Comment: yeah, not it is working! But I wanted to make it animated like on: https://codepen.io/enbee81/pen/LBMKqV. Do you know where I should put this code to make it a little bit fancy?

Comment: You have to put the image in a container wraped by some other containers. Have a deeper look the DEV Tools of your Browser (F12) to understand what's going on there!

Comment: At the very top of your section before styles html, try: {% load static %}

Comment: I have already added it into my code.

Comment: Guys I think there is a little bit misunderstanding. I would like to know how to edit/where to enter a code which is for example on https://codepen.io/Rplus/pen/lEDBj to use it on my website with my image.

Comment: Copy the the complete HTML Code of the CodePen Tutorial and then change the image. After  that copy the whole CSS of the CodePen Tutorial in external CSS-File and link your html with this CSS together:
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-style.css">
</head>

Comment: Thanks for your comment but could you please be more specific? 
1. Where I should copy the HTML code? Before my code/after/somewhere in the middle?
2. What do you mean by 'change the image'? I know there is a link to different image in CSS code but should I change something in my code as well?
3. Where I should link my HTML with CSS by <head></head>. Again, before/after/in the middle of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution how the manage the first CodePen Tutorial with two files! So you only need e.g. a index.html and a style.css File.

If you don't know how to link a external CSS File do this in your html File:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-awesome-stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

In this case the »my-awesome-stylesheet.css« must be in the same folder!

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background: #003;
        }

        .container {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .box {
            width: 60vmin;
            height: 60vmin;
            border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
            position: relative;

            &::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
                transform: scale(1.42);
            }
        }

        .spin-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            animation: spin 12s linear infinite;
            position: relative;
        }

        .shape {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transition: border-radius 1s ease-out;
            border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
            animation: morph 8s ease-in-out infinite both alternate;
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        .bd {
            width: 142%;
            height: 142%;
            position: absolute;
            left: -21%;
            top: -21%;
            /* This is the image you have to change! */
            background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519345182560-3f2917c472ef?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=2868fd5c3f30697d38732224e0ef51ed);
            background-size: 100%;
            background-position: center center;
            display: flex;
            color: #003;
            font-size: 5vw;
            font-weight: bold;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            animation: spin 12s linear infinite reverse;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        @keyframes morph {
            0% {
                border-radius: 40% 60% 60% 40% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
            }

            100% {
                border-radius: 40% 60%;
            }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            to {
                transform: rotate(1turn);
            }
        }
```

```html
    <!-- Here is enough space für other HTML Stuff -->

    <!-- THE CODEPEN BASIS HTML -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="spin-container">
                <div class="shape">
                    <div class="bd"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF THE CODEPEN BASIS HTML -->
    
    <!-- Here is enough space für other HTML Stuff -->
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).